# Use minute(of the day) for showing hours in dc js x axis

Tags: javascript, time, d3.js, scale, dc.js

I have minutes of a day i.e., form 0 to 1440.

Currently I am showing these minutes as it is, but how do I show it into hours.
For example:

```
3:AM ......... 4:AM.........5:AM
```

I tried several others things but no luck till now.

Here is what I am doing currently:

```
.x(d3.scale.linear().range(1, chartWidth).domain([1, 1440]))
```

And here is what I have tried:

```
d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2013,0,2), new Date(2013, 0, 3)])
```

This show the time exactly how I want but the graph doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may not have set the `.xUnits` correctly.  You probably want `.xUnits(d3.time.hours)` for what you are doing.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#xunitsxunits-function

Basically, .xUnits always has to match the scale.

This is a very common gotcha with dc.js and we'd like to eliminate the xUnits, but we don't know how to.  It is used to determine the number of points/bars.